# Error: Could not resolve the package 'cloud_firestore' in 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart'. in flutter

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

This is my pubspec.yaml. How I fix this error. Error is Could not resolve the package 'cloud_firestore' in 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart'. in flutter

```
dependencies:
firebase_core: ^0.7.0
firebase_auth: ^0.20.1
cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0+1
firebase: ^8.0.0
```

Comment: If you are still getting the same error, could you please run in your terminal the following commands: **1) flutter channel dev** ,   **2) flutter upgrade** and let me know if you still face the same issue? Or you can also run **flutter clean** command and Be sure you had run the **flutter pub get** command after executing previous commands.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely at the indentation so make sure that you have the right amount of spaces that is 2 spaces like shown below:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
  provider: ^4.3.3
```

Comment: I already followed above mentioned order(your order). But Error is displayed.

Comment: Did you type in terminal "flutter pub get" after you added the dependencies?